# ImportError: cannot import name 'VectorStoreIndex' from 'llama_index.core' (unknown location) after upgrading llama-index package

Tags: llama-index

I have tried to upgrade llama-index package like what the other posts has advised. However, i keep running into `ImportError: cannot import name 'VectorStoreIndex' from 'llama_index.core' (unknown location)` . Does anyone see the same thing?

Upgraded the package, but still doens't work!

Comment: check version of the package `llama_index` by running
`import llama_index
print(llama_index.__version__)`
 it appears that you have pre v0.10.0 version of the package.